# Как использовать LIB от другого компилятора?

Tags: rtl, c++, lib

Имеется LIB, собранная в BC3.1, она использует его RTL. Собственно, вопрос заключается в том, как воспользоваться этой библиотекой в другом компиляторе? Исходников библиотеки, понятное дело, нет. Есть ли способ собрать "добавку" в BC3.1 к этой библиотеке, которую потом спокойно использовать в другом компиляторе?

Comment: так как Вы не указали, в каком компиляторе собираетесь использовать, то ответ - 99% нет.

Comment: Компилятор OpenWatcom. И почему нет? Вы могли бы обосновать?

Comment: потому что у большинства компиляторов формат lib файлов свой. Плюс, если там используются классы, то и rtti различный. Плюс, ещё различная битность может быть.

В целом попробуйте, но заработает ли...

Comment: Т.е. LIB ДОЛЖНА содержать весь необходимый объектный код для своей линковки, в том числе, и RTL. В данную LIB RTL не включен, так как он часть проприетарного BC 3.1. Закрытый и/или проприетарный код RTL зло, которое привязывает к конкретному компилятору. Все ли я правильно понимаю?

Comment: то, что библиотека будет содержать внутри себя весь код RTL, ещё ничего не значит. Может быть функция, которая создает объект, а освобождать его будете в своем коде. В этом случае часто даже разные версии одного компилятора приводят к разным последствиям, а разные компиляторы...

А закрытый ли RTL или нет... какая разница?

Я вижу, что уже полгода назад почти такой же вопрос задавался и именно Вами. За это время уже можно и библиотеку переписать было.

Comment: Ну если библиотека что то там создает, она должна иметь документированный способ удалить то что на создавала. А будет она это делать встроенным сборщиком мусора или мне придется вызвать библиотечную функцию мне все равно. Открытость RTL как раз позволяет прояснить такие моменты как управление памятью. А переписать библиотеку это потрясающая мысль, вы могли бы начать сразу с нее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам необходимо будет сделать библиотеку-прослойку. Поскольку исходная lib использует RTL, взаимодействовать с нею нужно только компилятором версии, в которой она была собрана.
Соответственно, при помощи этого компилятора необходимо собрать новую библиотеку, которая будет клиентом к исходной, предоставлять интерфейс к функциональности исходной, и этот интерфейс должен удовлетворять ряду "переносимых" критериев:

1. "Ansi C" интерфейс. Т.е. никаких экспорта классов, никакого экспорта STL и т.п.. Экспорт только функций, входные и выходные параметры только стандартные типы.
2. Никаких include-ов стандартных библиотек. Если Вы сделаете один header, в идеале ему вообще не нужно содержать сторонних include-ов. Если содержит, в идеале это "Ansi C", как, например, "windows.h" (могу ошибаться, но, вроде бы, он без включений STL, классов и т.п.)
3. Библиотека не будет бросать никакие exception. Все их от исходной необходимо обрабатывать, но не пробрасывать выше. Перехвать exception компиляторозависим.
4. Вся память, выделяемая внутри библиотеки, должна освобождаться внутри библиотеки. Если где-то управление жизнью выделенной памяти передается клиенту, то интерфейсу надо иметь функцию, которая будет позволять освобождать такую память.
5. Лучше отказаться от абстрактных структур. Теоретически это не должно быть проблемой, но многие детали реализации виртуализации не стандартизированы, а значит компиляторы могут выполнять их по-разному, и это на практике (у меня между MinGW и VS разных версий, хотя между разными компиляторами MinGW и между разными VS такой проблемы не наблюдал) приводит к проблемам.

Вроде бы ничего не забыл.